# Rails: Creating an array with an incrementing attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so don't tear me apart! I apologize if my question is too long or basic, but I think it would be easier for all involved to understand my problem if I type plainly, clearly, and plentifully. If my question formatting can be improved, please let me know for later questions.

To put things in context, I am creating a Ruby on Rails app that involves displaying an array of records(**Times**) on Googlegraphs. There are two important attributes of these **Times** records; their **'date'** attribute and **'hours_worked'** attribute. Simply put, I need to display all of the **'hours_worked'** on a specific dates on the graph. So the first element of the array to be displayed on the graph holds all of the **'hours_worked'** values for the first date, the second element holds all of the **'hours_worked'** values for the second date, and so on.

Obviously I can't just put all of the records **'hours_worked'** values into an array, because then the **'date'** attribute would be completely ignored. If I had an array of **'hours_worked'** where two elements were on the same **'date'**, the graph wouldn't know this and would simply display them all without acknowledging the **'date'** at all.

My "Solution" with pseudo-code:

I though that I could try to iterate through all of **'Time'** records and split them into records whose **'dates'** already existed in one array, and put all of the copies in another array:

```
@array1 = []#Original values
@array2 = []

@task.time_and_attendances.each do |f|
 if f.date is not in @array2
 @array2 << f

else

  @array1 << f
```

Then I wanted to compare the two arrays and, if @array2 contained any dates that @array1 contained, simply add the **'hours_worked'** together. Because @array1 would contain all of the records that required this addition, dates that have several records would just have their **'hours_worked'** attribute combined. This would give me an array where each value is the total amount of **'hours_worked'** for every single date.

That would be the ideal solution to my problem, but I am stumped about how to implement it. Does anyone out there have any ideas?

Comment: So for each date you want to display the total number of hours worked on that date? What does your database schema look like?

Comment: The Times Record has both the date and hours_worked attributes, no other tables are involved. Edit: And to your first question, yep!

Comment: Sounds like a job for sql's GROUP and SUM... let the database do the data reduction for you. Sum the hours worked, grouped by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Time.select('date, sum(hours_worked) as total_hours_worked').group('date(date)')
```

That should give you an array of Time objects with date and total_hours_worked attributes.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks ramblex! By the way, do you know of any websites where I could learn how to better use SQL with Rails? I know a bit of SQL from a few years back and could use the experience. Edit: And I accepted your answer as the right one, that's how Stackoverflow works right?

Comment: The guide on Active Record is probably worth a read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html. Welcome to StackOverflow!